# Angular-Chart.js chart doesn't shown, if data added automatically

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, chart.js, ng2-charts

I've used this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-multiple-charts . It works fine with static data, but when I push data from the database (firebase realtime database) into the chart, it doesn't get drawn. However, the data is being pushed.

This is the method to retrieve data:

```
 retrieveResults(): void {
    this.srService.getAll().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(data => {
     this.result = data;

     /**
      * Iteration through the entity
      */ 
     this.result.forEach(e => {
      
      /**
       * Push Dataset from Database to line chart
       */   
      /*
      this.lineChartData.push(
      {
        labels: ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50'],
          datasets: [{
            data: [
             this.lineChartStart, 
             e.resultOne,
             e.resultTwo,
             e.resultThree,
             e.resultFour,
             this.lineChartEnd].reverse(),
            borderColor: 'yellow',
            fill: false
          }]
        });
      
      });     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When the chart data or options are changed, you need to invoke `chart.update()`.

> Please consult the chapter [Updating Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) from Chart.js documentation.

Comment: I solved the problem differently. In the canvas I`ve set data instead of the dataset ``` 
                              <canvas baseChart *ngFor="let d of lineChartData"
                                  [data]="d.data" 
                                  ....
                                  >
                              </canvas>
                       ```